# How can I save an Access database as ACCDE (from VBA)?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am developing an application in Access. What I would like to do is be able to script the creation of a deployed version.

For this, I want to:

- Rename a macro (m_AutoKey) to AutoKey
- Compile VBA code
- Change the ribbon (through File --> Options --> Current Database --> Ribbon Name) to "Block Options" (this is a custom USysRibbon entry)
- Save as ACCDE

This is what I have currently, which admittedly is pitiful, since I use sendkeys twice. I am able to do 3/4 of them however.

```
Public Sub MakeDeployable()

    'how can I do this? All examples seem to use
    'Me.RibbonName which sets it for a form, not globally
    'Application.RibbonName = "Block Options"

    'this works... (from a button)
    Dim i As Integer
    SendKeys "%ft"
    SendKeys "c"

    For i = 1 To 18
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    Next i

    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    SendKeys "{UP}"
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"

    'this works
    DoCmd.Rename "AutoKeys", acMacro, "m_AutoKeys"



    'force a compile (from a button)
    SendKeys "%{F11}%di"


    'I don't know how to do "SaveAs ACCDE" basically
    Dim sourceDB As String
    Dim targetDB As String
    sourceDB = Application.CurrentDb.Name
    targetDB = Left(sourceDB, InStrRev(sourceDB, "\")) & "myTest.accde"
    'application.ConvertAccessProject sourcedb, targetdb,

End Sub
```

- How can I save the application as an ACCDE via VBA?

Comment: Have you looked at Application.RunCommand acCmdMakeMDEFile?  I'm not sure if it would output the correct format.

Comment: You might also want to look at this. http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/make-accde-vba-t3385399.html Although, it doesn't seem that the command action (603) is documented. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820994(v=office.15).aspx